# Motion/Material Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: swift, cosmicmind, material-swift

I'm using latest version Material library for Swift (2.16.0). And in my project I have NavigationDrawer controller with ToolBarController as root view controller. Then I try to present modally SearchBarController, motion animation worked perfectly

```
let searchController = AppStoryboard.Tree.viewController(viewControllerClass: SearchViewController.self)
let searchBarController = SearchBarController(rootViewController: searchController)
searchBarController.isMotionEnabled = true
searchBarController.motionTransitionType = .autoReverse(presenting: .fade)
toolbarController?.present(searchBarController, animated: true)
```

But in log I see messages:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Material.SearchBarController: 0x7f8db554bde0>.
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <NavigationDrawerController: 0x7f8db680b000>.
```

I know, that Motion library have `transition(to: <UIViewController>)` method. But this method does not work for me, because it replaces the `rootViewController`

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in [CosmicMind/Motion #42](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Motion/pull/42) and released in `Motion 1.4.3` which is shipped with `Material 2.16.3`